# How to only print a specific line from a For loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

Basically I have a dictionary with 10 elements and I'm replacing user input string with those stored in the dictionary like so

```
abc_dict { 'a':'Apple','b':'Banana','c':'Cat'}:
str = user input
for key, value in abc_dict.iteritems():
    str = str.replace(key, value)
        print str
```

However when I print this it prints a line for each element in the dictionary and only the last line is fully replaced.
Example of my output

```
I like a, b, and c
I like apple, banana, and c
I like apple, banana, and cat
```

What concept must I use in order for it to only print the last line

Comment: Unindent the `print str` line until it is outside of the loop.

Comment: @zondo why must the print statement be outside the loop? I have another loop with a print statement inside of it but its under an "if" statement so does it depend on the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code:

```
abc_dict { 'a':'Apple','b':'Banana','c':'Cat'}:
str = user input
for key, value in abc_dict.iteritems():
    str = str.replace(key, value)
print str
```

Your error: you use `print str` inside the `for` loop

Comment: so essentially in every loop the "print"  must go outside of the loop in order for it to be effective?

Comment: @juan Everything you put inside the for loop is executed on _every run_ of the for loop. That is what loops are for. If you don't want something executed every time you run a loop, don't put it in a loop. If you `print` inside a for loop, it will print on every run of the loop. If you don't want `print` to execute on every run, put it outside and it will only run after the loop is finished. As simple as that.

Comment: @juan IF you need `print` to run at a specific point in the for loop, rather than after the loop ends, look into [if statements](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html).